# What should unit test cover in a list display app from api?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I have an app that connects to an API endpoint and displays a list of people. I want to write a unit test for the app. But I am not sure what to test here. There is no arithmetic operation happening It's just fetching the data from API and displaying it.

What should the unit test cover in such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If a test can never fail, then it's not really testing anything. In your case though, a network api call is being made. And network calls can fail all the time. Depending on how you are making your network call you can either:

1. create a fake web server that can return a variety of error codes
2. create a mock api service that can return a variety of error codes
3. don't test anything

There are all kinds of tests you can use, behavioural, unit, functional, integration, black box, user acceptance testing.

What does testing do for you? Does it document code behaviour? Does it lock in the behavior of a function? Does it ensure that something works?

Depending on your needs, you may not need a test. Or, you may need a lot more. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests are designed to ensure that a behavior or set of behaviors occur(s) when you invoke a unit of code.

In this case, you have code that is fetching the data from an API and returning it. You might want to test the following:

1. Your code makes a network call to the API.
2. When the API returns a successful response, your app renders the data.
3. When the API returns a failed response, you gracefully handle the failure.

Of course these steps will probably vary depending on your use case. You can look into stubbing the API to understand how you can simulate API invocation failures.